# How can I delete selected <tr>(parent) div every time a button (child) is clicked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, parent

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="input">
            <p>Room 1: </p>
        </div>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="revenue-input">
            <input type="number" min="0" id="room1rev" size="1" placeholder="0">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="btn-del-rev" class="btn-del">-</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="input">
            <p>Room 2: </p>
        </div>  
    </td>
    <td >
        <div class="revenue-input">
            <input type="number" min="0" id="room2rev" size="1" placeholder="0">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="btn-del-rev" class="btn-del">-</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
<!-- Delete Element -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-del-rev").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove()
    });
});
</script>
```

When the button with the #btn-del-rev id is clicked it removes the entire tr structure (parent, etc.) However, clicking the same button on the next row doesn't remove the next tr.

I understand that it's a problem with reusing an id, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to have the button work across all tr that I want deleted without creating a unique id, and redundant jQuery code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html duplicated "id"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059438/html-duplicated-id)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**An ID must be unique !**

Change or remove the ID attribute in your HTML

```
<button class="btn-del">-</button>
```

And use the .class attribute instead

```
$(".btn-del").click(function() {
```

By the way, instead of `.parent().parent()`, you should use `.closest()`

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove()
```

> get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[jQuery Closest documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Exactly what I needed to change. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ID's can't be repeated in a page, they are unique by definition.

You need to change that to a class instead

Answer (score 0):

You're using IDs and for multiple buttons you should use CLASS names. So you better transform that `btn-del-rev` to a class.

Answer (score 0):

The IDs must be unique, so you may change them to class.

In order to remove only the parent div you need to change this line:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove()
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('div.revenue-input').remove()
```

The [.closest('tr')](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) selects the parent row, while the find selects the div.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".btn-del-rev").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('div.revenue-input').remove()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="input">
                <p>Room 1: </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="revenue-input">
                <input type="number" min="0" id="room1rev" size="1" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn-del-rev btn-del">-</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="input">
                <p>Room 2: </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="revenue-input">
                <input type="number" min="0" id="room2rev" size="1" placeholder="0">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn-del-rev btn-del">-</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the id a class

```
 <button class="btn-del-rev btn-del">-</button>
```

Use the class, then get closest row

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-del-rev").on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```