# changing the selected value of element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below html and jquery:

```js
var result = {
  "TPS on Desktop": "Green",
  'TPS on mobile': 'Amber'
};

for (var key in result) {
  $('td[id="checklist"]').each(function() {
    if (JSON.stringify($(this).text().trim() === key)) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td[class="tdcolor"] select option:selected').val(result[key]);
      console.log(key + ' : ' + $(this).closest('tr').find('td[class="tdcolor"] select option:selected').val());
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="decisionTable" class="CSSTableGenerator" width="100%" border=1 id="table1">
<tr color="23145">
    <th><b>CheckList</b></th>
    <th><b>Health</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="checklist">
        TPS on Desktop
    </td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
        <select class="health">
            <option value=0>Select</option>
            <option value="1">Green</option>
            <option value="2">Amber</option>
            <option value="3">Red</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="checklist">
        TPS on Mobile
    </td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
        <select class="health">
            <option value=0>Select</option>
            <option value="1">Green</option>
            <option value="2">Amber</option>
            <option value="3">Red</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Using the above jquery, I want to change the value of the dropdown in `tdcolor` td element and the same should reflect on the web page. But, I've not had luck with above code, however `console.log` output of the selected value says the new value is updated but the same isn't reflected.

Could you please help me in solving this issue? I want to change the color of `tdcolor` based on the colors passed in `result` map.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use  *Duplicate Ids* `checklist`, use data-id instead,

Comment: @gurvinder372, thanks.. actually I'm using `checklist` in other js functions. So, cannot change it. Will check on `data-id`. Thanks

Comment: You can not use two same `ids` in single page.

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet and it didn't work, so I added `.trim()` thinking it was because I changed the formatting.  A quick look at how it was before the edit shows that the format wasn't changed for that part.   `$(this).text() === key`     `.text()` will include spaces, so make sure it's `.trim()`'d.   Rest still didn't work with this change though.

Comment: Can you explain why you stringify true/false to get a true / **falsey** value?  `if (JSON.stringify($(this).text().trim() === key))` rather than just `if ($(this).text().trim() === key)`

Comment: yeah, I tried with `if ($(this).text().trim() === key)`, it worked in my application. It didn't work in `jsfiddler` so I had to use `JSON.stringify` and it worked. Not sure with the reason though.

Comment: I'm doing this on a page load action, fetching the values of `result` from database and setting up in webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html duplicated "id"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059438/html-duplicated-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use duplicate ids, **id** value should be unique. Use another attribute like **data-id** instead.

Also, no need to use nested iterations

```js
var result = {
  "TPS on Desktop": "Green",
  'TPS on Mobile': 'Amber'
};

$('td[data-id="checklist"]').each(function() 
{
    var value = result[ $(this).html().trim() ];
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td[class="tdcolor"] select option:contains(' + value + ')').prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="decisionTable" class="CSSTableGenerator" width="100%" border=1 id="table1">
  <tr color="23145">
    <th><b>CheckList</b></th>
    <th><b>Health</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="checklist">
      TPS on Desktop
    </td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select class="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="checklist">
      TPS on Mobile
    </td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select class="health">
             <option value=0>Select</option>
             <option value="1">Green</option>
             <option value="2">Amber</option>
             <option value="3">Red</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many Thanks, will try to add this to my application. This is working in fiddler. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function(){ 
    var value = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var txtVal = $(this).parent().parent().find('#checklist').text();
  console.log(txtVal.trim()+':'+value.trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="decisionTable" class="CSSTableGenerator" width="100%" border=1 id="table1">
  <tr color="23145">
    <th><b>CheckList</b></th>
    <th><b>Health</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="checklist">
      TPS on Desktop
    </td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select class="health">
        <option value=0>Select</option>
        <option value="1">Green</option>
        <option value="2">Amber</option>
        <option value="3">Red</option>
       </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="checklist">
      TPS on Mobile
    </td>
    <td class="tdcolor">
      <select class="health">
        <option value=0>Select</option>
        <option value="1">Green</option>
        <option value="2">Amber</option>
        <option value="3">Red</option>
       </select>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```